# How to delete duplicate results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table with two columns which is generated by a query in SQL:

```
Lookup Value  Result
1             2
2             1
4             3
3             4
```

As you can see it contains duplicate results. I only want it to show the first line and the third line. Does anyone know how to do this in SQL?

Thanks

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: There are no duplicates there...

Comment: Why 3rd and not 4th? Does it matter?

Comment: Hi jarlh 
It doesn't matter if 3rd or 4th row

Comment: @IvanS. - `1|2` not equals `2|1`

Comment: @OTARIKI In [**dominoes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominoes) are the same.

Comment: @Juan  - But as table rows, they are not same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods.  Here is one using `union all`:

```
select t.*
from t
where col1 < col2
union all
select t1.*
from t1
where col1 > col2 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t1.col1 = t2.col2 and t1.col2 = t2.col1);
```

If you always know that both pairs exist (as in your sample data), you can just use:

```
select t.*
from t
where col1 < col2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       CASE WHEN Lookup Value  < Result
            THEN Lookup Value
            ELSE Result
       END as first,
       CASE WHEN Lookup Value  < Result
            THEN Result
            ELSE Lookup Value
       END as second
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Juan .. this might generate rows which aren't in the table when there are no symmetric duplicates. Eg: (6,4) might come out as (4,6)

Comment: @vkp, You are totally right. But Op says he want `(1,2)` over `(2,1)` but `(4,3)` over `(3,4)` for no particular reason. So my guess is tuple order doesnt matter, like dominoes pieces.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table T (
[Lookup Value] int,
Result int
)

Insert into T values (1,2),(2,1),(4,3),(3,4)

Select distinct T.[Lookup Value], T.Result
From T
where T.[Lookup Value]<=T.Result
```